# IllegalArgumentException: Failed to serialize object

Tags: java, serialization, orientdb

I need to implement **OSerializableStream** interface in order to save objects in [orientdb](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/) database. I use *orientdb-community-1.7.4* version and tried to use **SerializationUtils** in spring to serialize, deserialize the objects. When I want to serialize objects with attribute `Map<Integer, Collection<String>>`, I get error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to serialize object
```

**SocialRecord.java**

```
package persistence.graphdb.socialNetwork;

import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.OSerializableStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils;

public class SocialRecord implements OSerializableStream{

    // all message keywords
    private Map<Integer, Collection<String>> keywords = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Integer, Collection<String>> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(Map<Integer, Collection<String>> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] toStream() throws OSerializationException {
        return SerializationUtils.serialize(this);
    }

    @Override
    public OSerializableStream fromStream(byte[] bytes) throws OSerializationException {
        return (OSerializableStream) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
    }

}
```

When I create some objects of *SocialRecord* class and call *toStream()* method, I get *IllegalArgumentException*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HashMap rather as it implemts serializer. You may also need to subclass your Collection, as I've found that more complex objects are tricky

Comment: I tried to change Map<Integer, Collection<String>> for HashMap<Integer, List<String>>, but it didn't helped

Answer (score 2):

The SerializationUtils probably needs a class that implements Serializable.

[edit]  after comment below I now believe issue is the Map member.  Change its type to serializeable type HashMap and I believe the issue will resolve.

Comment: Do you mean argument of serialize() method? I don't think so, because if I remove keywords attribute, serialization works.

Comment: Try changing Map to HashMap.  Map is an interface an not serializable.

Comment: I tried to change Map<Integer, Collection<String>> for HashMap<Integer, List<String>>, but it didn't helped